# Connecting already exisiting AWS Cognito userpool to a new Cloudformation Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I already have an AWS cognito userpool,now i am creating a cloudformation stack for AWS Chime SDK,how can i manipulate the template.yaml file of the stack inorder to connect the existing cognito userpool,instead of creating a new userpool for the stack.

Answer (score 0):

While CloudFormation can generally import existing resources, Cognito does not seem to be supported at the moment, according to the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html).

Comment: So is there any way to implement what i want?Connecting already existing userpool to the cloudformation stack.

Comment: No, unfortunately not.